# Hibernate Postload and null fields on referenced entities

Tags: hibernate, null, field, onload

I have two entities like the ones below:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
   @Id
   private id;
   private String name;

   ...
}

@Entity
public class Person {
   @Id
   private id;
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private Project project;

   @PostLoad
   void onLoad(){
      if (project.getName() == null){
         //It's always null!!!
      }
   }


   ...
}
```

As the code says, on onLoad the field of the related entity is always null -in fact, all field of related entity are null-. I need Hibernate to fetch the field before calling onLoad.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a `Fetch strategy` it might be:

```
FetchType.LAZY
```

or

```
FetchType.EAGER
```

You should define also the join column with the foreign ID.

In your code:

```
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
```